# UPDATE with a SELECT to create a ranking (effiency)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sqlperformance

I have a ranking that every X time has a balance added to the total points of each player, changing how they are ranked.
I want my rank to be calculated at DB (MySQL), but I want it to be efficient, so first things first, here's the BalanceIn code:

Q1:

```
UPDATE     playerscore
SET        points = points * 0.9 + GREATEST(-100, LEAST(100, balance)),
           balance = 0;
```

Once the `points` are updated for all them, I want to reorder the rank (only for ranked players), like so:

Q2:

```
SET        @r = 0;
UPDATE     playerscore p
INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT   @r:=@r+1 as new_rank, player_id
            FROM     playerscore
            WHERE    is_ranked = 1
            ORDER BY points DESC) s
ON         p.player_id = s.player_id
SET        p.rank = s.new_rank
WHERE      is_ranked = 1;
```

It works, and solves my problem, but: **is thisgoing to make 1 select, and from here update all values, or will it make a select for each playerscore row?**

In pseudocode, that's what I **DO NOT** want:

```
foreach PlayerScore p in playescore
    new = get_all_players_sorted
    update p.rank = new.new_rank where p.player_id = new.player_id
endforeach
```

As it will be, for N players: N selects + N updates.
I want it to be: 1 select + N updates (contained in a single update) like so:

```
new = get_all_players_sorted
foreach PlayerScore p in playescore
    update p.rank = new.new_rank where p.player_id = new.player_id
endforeach
```

**Am I doing it right with my query (Q2)??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your query, you can perhaps speed it up by rephrasing the query and using an index.

The index you want is `playerscore(is_ranked, points desc)`.  The query is:

```
SET @r = 0;

UPDATE playerscore p
    SET p.rank = (@r := @r + 1)
    WHERE is_ranked = 1
    ORDER BY points desc;
```

In MySQL, you can use `order by` with `update` -- as long as you are not using a `join`.  In this case, you don't need a `join` because you are setting the variable as a separate statement.

Comment: works really nice and fast! tested with 100k registers and took less than a second to complete both `Q1` + `Q2` :)